# Flutter: How to adjust the size of ElevatedButton which is a child element of ListView. And why we can use Align widget at this situation?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(home:MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:ListView(
        children:[
          SizedBox(height:50.0,),
          SizedBox(
            width:200.0,
            height:200.0,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child:Text('push'),
              onPressed:(){},

            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The first question: Why can't the width of the ElevatedButton, a child element of ListView, be adjusted using SizedBox in the above code?
Even though the width is specified as 200.0 in SizedBox, the button expands to the full width of the screen.

(The height of the button can be adjusted.)

---

The second question: as a solution to the above situation, I was able to adjust the width of the button using margin as below.

```
          Container(
            margin:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0,),
            child: SizedBox(
              width:200.0,
              height:200.0,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child:Text('push'),
                onPressed:(){},
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

This works, but using margin doesn't seem to be a very intuitive way to specify the size.

So, as a result of searching for other methods, it became possible to adjust the width by wrapping with Align as shown below.

```
          Align(
            child: SizedBox(
              width:300.0,
              height:200.0,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child:Text('push'),
                onPressed:(){},
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I think this method is more intuitive, but I'm not sure why we can adjust the width by wrapping it with ***Align***.

At this point, my perception is that the Align widget is generally used to specify the on-screen position of child widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Its Default behavior of `ListView`. it will take the full width/height if you set the axis as vertical/horizontal.
By default, the axis is set as vertical.

For that, you can use `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 50.0,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 200.0,
        height: 200.0,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('push'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I will investigate related matters.